# Problems citing letters published in articles in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I'm having trouble citing `@letter`s printed as part of an `@article` using `biblatex-chicago`. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[utf8,12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@letter{Raux18101789Bertin,
author = {Raux, {Nicolas Joseph}},
title = {Nicolas Joseph Raux to Henri Bertin},
shorttitle = {to Bertin, 18 October 1789},
origlocation = {Peking},
origdate = {1789-10-18},
xref = {Cordier1913LesCorrespondants},
options = {skipbib=true}
}

@letter{Raux12111789Bertin,
author = {Raux, {Nicolas Joseph}},
title = {Nicolas Joseph Raux to Henri Bertin},
shorttitle = {to Bertin, 12 November 1789},
origlocation = {Peking},
origdate = {1789-11-12},
xref = {Cordier1913LesCorrespondants},
options = {skipbib=true}
}

@letter{Raux17111786Bertin,
author = {Raux, {Nicolas Joseph}},
title = {Nicolas Joseph Raux to Henri Bertin},
shorttitle = {to Bertin, 17 November 1786},
origlocation = {Peking},
origdate = {1786-11-17},
xref = {Cordier1913LesCorrespondants},
options = {skipbib=true}
}

@article{Cordier1913LesCorrespondants,
author = {Cordier, Henri},
journal = {T'oung Pao},
volume = {14},
number = {2},
pages = {227--257},
origdate = {1784/1790},
date = {1913},
addendum = {letters originally written 1784--1790},
title = {Les Correspondants de Bertin, Secrétaire d'état au \textsc{xviii}\textsuperscript{e} siècle}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[notes,strict,isbn=false,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

.\footcite{Raux18101789Bertin}

.\footcite{Raux12111789Bertin}

.\footcite{Raux17111786Bertin}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The citations produced look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the first citation doesn't appear correctly.

There is a secondary formatting issue stemming from the fact that `biblatex-chicago` doesn't seem to like to cite `letters` in `article`s (if it did so correctly, I would want to see the journal name etc in the first citation of every `letter`, but that is not the case). Although I'd love to find a solution to this secondary problem as well, my issue here is first and foremost with the fact that the `xref` doesn't seem to work in the first `letter` I cite, no matter which one I put first.

I compile with `xelatex`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using just `crossref` instead of `xref`? I've had problems with the latter.

Comment: The problem is that an `@letter` does not have an `journal` field, and the `crossref` will at most copy the `@articles` `journal` field to the  child `@letter`, but it is simply ignored there. You could simply cite the `@article` and then add a short remark as to who sent what to whom in the postnote. The fact that this problem appears only with the first letter is thanks to subsequent citations using a short citation for the `@article`, while the first tries to use a full citation. If you cite the `@article` before all `@letter`s you get the short citation anywhere.